# Get selected option jquery on change function is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I am select dropdown option then does'not assign the value of selected option in hidden field.

Please correct Where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
include("../common/config.php");

$time = time();
$id=$_REQUEST['dr_id'];

$allEst = $db->select(array("*"),PREFIX."obligation_pharmacy","obligation_id IN ($id)");
    }
  ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function populate(unique,sel){
alert(sel.value);
$("#pharmacy_id"+unique).val(sel.value);
}
</script>

   <select name="pharmacy_name[]" class="name" id="pharmacy_name<?php echo $time?>" style="width:180px; font-size:11px;" onchange="populate(<?php echo $time?>,this)">
   <option value="">Select Pharmacy Name</option>
   <?php
      foreach($allEst as $ss)
        {if($ss->pharmacy_name!=''){?>
         <option value="<?php echo $ss->id;?>"><?php echo $ss->pharmacy_name; ?></option>
        <?php }} ?>  

  </select>
     <input type="hidden" name="pharmacy_id[]" id="pharmacy_id<?php echo $time?>" value="">
```

Comment: 1. i am unable to see any jQuery library added in your code.2. No need to pass any value to function

Comment: tip. using `$_REQUEST` is a very bad idea. There are security issues

Comment: my id is unique that'why i need to pass value to function

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, usually something like this:

```
$('#my-select').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#my-hidden-input').val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pharmacy_name').change(function(){

      // get selected option value
      var option_val = $( "#pharmacy_name option:selected" ).val(); 

      // populate hidden field
      $('#pharmacy_id').val(option_val); 
}
```